# Getting parsing error when trying to parse a YML file

Tags: parsing, yaml, cypress

as part of a using an in-house cypress test automation framework I am facing an error when parsing some yaml file, here is the error :

```
       "before each" hook for "[e2e] User performs basic ....":
       <ParseException> Unexpected characters near ",Instruction_Label:".
```

Here my yml structure :

```
Instruction_Label:
  locator: '[data-cy="personalInfo_Instruction_Label"]'
  ignore: true
Document_Type_Dropdown:
  locator: '[data-cy="personalInfo_Document_Type_Dropdown"]'
  ignore: true
```

I have noticed in the error a comma added at the beginning of the locator name  : ",Instruction_Label:"

An here is how I am parsing files :

```
cy.task('fileReader', ['./src/configs/yamls/kyc-ux/verifCenterPage.yml', './src/configs/yamls/kyc-ux/personalInfoPage.yml', './src/configs/yamls/kyc-ux/addressVerificationPage.yml', './src/configs/yamls/kyc-ux/countryOfResidencePage.yml', './src/configs/yamls/kyc-ux/documentVerificationPage.yml']).then(function (yamlList) {
            var yamlString = yamlList.map(function (item) {
                return item
            })
            cy.wrap(YAML.parse(yamlString.toString())).as('elementFactory')

        })
```

This used to work fine and I even tried to reset to previous commits where my tests used to pass but still getting the same error. Any clue please?

Comment: The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML based and looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format, which is what you have.

Answer (score -1):

Turned to be caused by trailing spaces in my file, the solution is either remove the spaces or add this :

```
var yamlString = yamlList.join('\n');
```